# Why am I receiving the "Cannot find property 'value' of null" error?

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting the "Cannot find property 'value' of null" error on line 2 of my JavaScript code. Whether or not I input strings on my text-box, I get this error. Any way I can go about fixing this?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Screen</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css"/>
        <script src="login.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <h1 onclick="loginDetails()">Login</h1>
            <form onsubmit="return validateLogin()">
                <label for="username" class="label-1">Username</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="username" class="text-box"><br>
                <label for="password" class="label-2">Password</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="password" class="text-box"><br>
                <button type="submit" id="login" class="button">Sign In</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validateLogin() {
    var username = document.getElementById(username).value;
    var password = document.getElementById(password).value;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Use valid IDs - like “username” (note the quotes). The code is asking to find undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thye need to be strings passed in:

```
function validateLogin() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    return false;
}
```